# Drawable downscaling not working for assets declared in another module

Tags: android, android-resources

*Sharing knowledge, Q&A style*

Consider an app architecture with a generic library module and multiple app modules that configure the library module. Library module references resources that are provided by the app modules. This enables target-specific optimisation: only ship app with resources that are used by that app variant.

To refer to resources in library module, using values resources to introduce identifiers:

```
<resources>
  <item name="foo" type="drawable"/>
</resources>
```

Then providing the asset in the app modules:

```
app1/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/foo.png # variant for app1
app2/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/foo.png # variant for app2
# app3 configuration does not use drawable/foo, no need to provide
```

The assets are not provided for each density bucket, instead relying on system [choosing the nearest match and scaling up or down as necessary](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) with good enough results.

Now when e.g. app1 is run on a mdpi density device such as a tablet, getting

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
Drawable app1.package.name:drawable/foo with resource ID #0x7f123456
```

This nearest-match resource loading works ok if the .png assets are included in the library module directly. Don't want to include all image assets there since that would bloat the app unnecessarily.

This nearest-match resource loading works ok when scaling up, e.g. xhdpi -> xxhdpi. Only the downscaling like xhdpi -> mdpi is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the crash issue by moving the .png assets to drawable-mdpi.

Comment: But how this satisfy your question criteria of relying on system to do the scaling ?

Comment: Or you moved all images from xhdpi to mdpi ?

Comment: Also what I learnt in the past, if you don't want to put images for all densities, keep them directly in drawable folder. Do you think that is correct too ?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Lint will complain. There are also other alternatives like anydpi and nodpi - https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html